# meaning of 'saw' here

Tags: word-meaning

This is from [a news article](https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/ryuichi-sakamoto-dies-intl/index.html).

> Outside music, Sakamoto was known for activism — and in particular for
> his anti-nuclear views, *which* **saw** him demonstrating against nuclear
> power plants and co-organizing a "No Nukes" concert in 2012.

I think the antecedent of the relative pronoun *which* is the entire previous clause.

If so, I wonder what the meaning of the **saw** is in the above context.

I can't find any definition of 'see' in the dictionary which is appropriate in the above context.

Comment: [3b: to be the setting or time of : *"The last fifty years have seen a sweeping revolution in science …" —Barry Commoner*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see)

Comment: @stangdon Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are distracted by the odd punctuation of the parenthetical clause 'and in particular for his anti-nuclear views', which (in my opinion) should have been preceded and followed by parentheses, em dashes or commas, instead of an em dash before and a comma after. If we remove that clause — as we can with parentheticals — we see that 'which' refers to Sakamoto's activism, and the meaning is as here:

> (transitive) to be characterized by
> *this period of history has seen much unrest*

[See (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see)

> Of things, places, etc.: To be contemporary with and in the
> neighbourhood of, to be the scene of (an event); to be in existence
> during (a period of time). Also of a period of time: **To be marked by
> (an event).**
>
> In 1906 Cambridge saw three or four of her most learned men compete for the Greek chair.

Oxford English Dictionary

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.